# Custom language parser distinct C-like type declarations from expressions

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I've been working on building a compiler for my own language (implemented using Python and LLVM). So far I've built an interactive Lexer which my parser asks for a token from a set of expected tokens based on the state of the parser.
parseValue member of Parser derived from Lexer

```
def parseValue(self):
        """Read in a Value of any kind, including complete expressions"""
        Token = self.NextToken({
                    'OP': ['group_open'],
                    'IDENT':['VARIABLE'],
                    'NUMBER': None,
                    'STRING': None})
        if Token.Type == 'OP':
            if Token.Special == 'GROUP_OPEN':
                laststate = self.state[-1]
                numstates = len(self.state)
                self.state.append('GROUP')
                expr = praseExpr() # Should pop 'GROUP' from state
                if numstates != len(self.state) or laststate != self.state[-1]:
                    self.Abort("Unexpected State")
                return Value('EXPR', expr)
            else:
                return None
        if Token.Type == 'IDENT':
            return Value('IDENT', Token)
        elif Token.Type == 'NUMBER':
            return Value('NUMBER', Token)
        elif Token.Type == 'STRING':
            return Value('STRING', Token)
        else:
            return None
```

Currently I've implemented Expression parsing using the shunting-yard algorithm
 and 3 member functions parseExpr, parseValue, parseOp.

This will translate some complex expression such as

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO("""\
x = 9; y = 7; z= 0.8;
k = sin(C["pi"]*x + y)*z;
type* m = y;
g[x](x,y);
""")
p = Parser(infile=buf)
while not p.EOF:
    print p.parseExpr()
```

to the following (this is a functional representation of the AST that was generated)

```
@SET(x,9)
@SET(y,7)
@SET(z,0.8)
@SET(k,@MUL(sin(@ADD(@MUL(@SUBSCRIPT(C,'pi'),x),y)),z))
@SET(@MUL(type,m),y)
@SUBSCRIPT(g,x)(x,y)
None
```

I would call parseExpr() anywhere where I expect to find an expression. However, I'm not sure what to do about statements since a statement could be some special syntax starting with a keyword i.e.

```
parseStmt(self):
    Token = self.NextToken({'IDENT': ['KEYWORD']})
    if Token.Type is not None:
         # handle for keyword here
         return stmt
    # This is the same point in the file as no valid token was found, and I can then handle just expressions by
    return self.parseExpr()
```

So my problem is how to handle type declarations since `type* m=y` is a valid expression if type is an object and `@MUL(type, m)` returns a lvalue which is allowed but its also a valid type declaration if type is the name of some type possibly user defined. Furthermore `type** m=y` is valid as a type declaration but not an expression since there no binary operator `**`, hence my current parser would read `type*` then give an value expected error message. Which is normally correct since type declarations are only valid in a few contexts.

Obviously I could use some keyword to declare variables, but personally I prefer the C-style syntax and this would lead to the question of what about function definitions — should the keyword be used there or not. I would prefer to avoid this solution and am hoping someone here can provide a solution to this problem. As none on the online articles I can find about parsing really apply since they either use generators or a different parsing model to what I'm using, hence they haven't been of much help.

Comment: Food for thought: declarations are one of the most confusing parts of the C grammar.  Since you're making your own language, you might consider *not* copying C here.

Comment: I have considered that possibility however I for simple type declarations C definitions are really nice from a code readability point of view i.e. saying 'int x' rather than 'var int x' or something similar, also I want a language that would be familiar to a C or C++ programmer. And I haven't been able to think up a clean alternative that would fit nicely into my language and include variable initialization similar to C/C++. However I'm open to suggestion if you have any ideas.